# How do I add custom tables to Syspro after creating them on SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I am unable to configure Syspro to see additional custom tables I have created in MS-SQL.

I have created a sample table within the same SysproCompany1 database and populated with some basic information. 
I then use Syspro power-tailing to customize a button with a vbscript. 
The script calls COMFND to retrieve the data.

```
XMLParam = XMLParam & "<Query>"
XMLParam = XMLParam & " <TableName>InvMaster</TableName>"
.....
XMLOut = CallBO("COMFND",XMLParam,"auto")
```

Using Standard Syspro databse table names it returns results. (Example: InvMaster)

If I specify my new custom table Syspro errors with a table not found message?

Do I need to define the additional tables in the Syspro config or schema?

Please could anyone advise where I can find this?

Many Thanks

Comment: What is SysPro?

Comment: SysPro is an ERP Business system with a Microsoft SQL Server database backend.

Comment: You may need to find some help forums on SysPro. There doesn't even seem to be a tag for that ERP here.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible using these business objects. If you need to ask more questions about this you can have a look at the [SYSPRO Forums](http://forums.syspro.com).